# Change global volumen with SoundJs

Tags: typescript, volume, createjs, soundjs

I'm creating an application in HTML5 using CreateJS. By starting with the part of sounds, using SoundJS, I have seen that has many limitations. The `createjs.Sound` object has the method of `play()` and `stop()`. But `play()` executes only a specific sound and `stop()` for all the sounds of the stage.

I wanted to know is if there is any way to define a global volume for all sounds and be able to go up or down at any time, although it sounds one or ten at a time.

I had initially thought the option to create a global variable and use it as a parameter of volume when playing a sound. My problem is that I use several classes in different files, and they all have independent sounds. They would need that variable out comprehensive beyond the classes and methods. I'm programming with typescript.

I can't use the master volumen for my problem. In the documentation, I can find:
`createjs.Sound.volume = 0.5;`

But it changes all the global volume. I need to separe the music and the sound effects in two different volume options.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do audio "groups" for volume, playback, or panning at this time. You would have to store off instances you want to control into arrays/groups, and then iterate those groups to set those values on each instance.

This could be a handy feature, so feel free to [log an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I make my own solution. I created two global boolean variables. One for the music and the other for the sounds. When I want to reproduce a new sound, check if this variable is set to True.

It works fine for me.